# React-Native CodePush Build Failure - No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push found

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am trying to enable codepush in my react native application. Using repo https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push
I am facing build failure on the following Environment

```
Environment:
=============
react-native-code-push version:7.0.4
react-native version:0.65.0
Gradle version: 6.9
Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build? : both
Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device?: during build, can't run it yet.
Hardware/OS: MacOS (M1 chipset), MacOS Monterey v12.0.1
```

According to documentation @https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-android.md#plugin-installation-and-configuration-for-react-native-060-version-and-above-android
i am following these steps

1. npm install --save react-native-code-push
2. In your android/settings.gradle file, make the following additions at the end of the file:

(a)

```
...
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
```

Also tried adding before the last line (though the documentation asks to add at the end of file)

(b)

```
...
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

3. In your android/app/build.gradle file, add the codepush.gradle file as an additional build task definition underneath react.gradle:

```
...
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
...
```

4. Update the MainApplication.java file to use CodePush via the following changes:

```
...
// 1. Import the plugin class.
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        ...

        // 2. Override the getJSBundleFile method in order to let
        // the CodePush runtime determine where to get the JS
        // bundle location from on each app start
        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
            return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }
    };
}
```

5. Add the Deployment key to strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AppName</string>
    <string moduleConfig="true" name="CodePushDeploymentKey">XXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Build output with step-2(a):

```
> Task :react-native-code-push:generateReleaseRFile FAILED
Dependency resolved to an incompatible version: Dependency(fromArtifactVersion=ArtifactVersion(groupId=com.nimbusds, artifactId=nimbus-jose-jwt, version=5.1), toArtifact=Artifact(groupId=net.minidev, artifactId=json-smart), toArtifactVersionString=[1.3.1,2.3])
Dependency resolved to an incompatible version: Dependency(fromArtifactVersion=ArtifactVersion(groupId=com.nimbusds, artifactId=nimbus-jose-jwt, version=5.1), toArtifact=Artifact(groupId=net.minidev, artifactId=json-smart), toArtifactVersionString=[1.3.1,2.3])

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-code-push:generateReleaseRFile'.
> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
   > In project 'App' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1
     .3.1,2.3]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

     Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1 -> net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3], but json-smart version was 2
     .3.

     The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
     ifact with the issue.
     -- Project 'App' depends on project 'react' which depends onto net.minidev:json-smart@{strictly 2.3}
     -- Project 'App' depends on project 'react' which depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@{strictly 5.1}
     -- Project 'App' depends on project 'react' which depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@5.1

     For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :App:assembleDebug to see the
      dependency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at http
     s://github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to yo
     ur build.gradle file.
   > In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.3.1
     ,2.3]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

     Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1 -> net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3], but json-smart version was 2
     .3.

     The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
     ifact with the issue.
     -- Project 'app' depends on project 'react' which depends onto net.minidev:json-smart@{strictly 2.3}
     -- Project 'app' depends on project 'react' which depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@{strictly 5.1}
     -- Project 'app' depends on project 'react' which depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@5.1

     For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
     endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
     github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
     uild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 48s
```

Build Output with step-2(b):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
```

Answer (score 1):

first thing You can try is 1. `npm start -- --reset-cache`
if that doesn't work try 2.  `./gradlew clean` in your android folder of root project.
if that also doesn't work I'll suggest you to upgrade your react-native version and code push version in react-native >0.71 we don't need
`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`
`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"`
remove it and try running your app